# syntax error: . or operator expected after expression 1 error(s) compilation failed

Tags: prolog

**Domains**

```
namelist=integer*;
```

**Predicates**

```
member12(namelist,namelist,namelist);
```

**Clauses**

```
member12([],L,L).
member12([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-
   member12(L1,L2,L3).
```

Comment: Add the full log for better clarity on the issue

Comment: Don't add informations in comments, edit your post to include this instead. Also, what is your question? You need to add **text** explaining what you want do, what you expect and what you get. Also I would have indented the last line.

Comment: You are trying to run Turbo Prolog code in SWI Prolog? You tagged this SWI Prolog, but the source you show is Turbo Prolog. Please clarify. Turbo Prolog source won't work in SWI Prolog as Turbo Prolog is off-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you didn't provide the entire code, and considering  your error, I'd say it's in your **Goal** part.

You probably have this line:

```
consult('D:\\Prolog\\list.pl')
```

And the error message states a ***"`.` or operator"*** is missing

```
consult('D:\\Prolog\\list.pl').
% here _______________________↑
```